# Is there a way to undo an action in OneNote?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, onenote

I use OneNote a lot on my Lumia 830 running Windows 10 Mobile.

The only feature I am missing is a way to undo last action, for example a line of text deleted by error etc.

Is there a way to undo in OneNote?

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any action history in OneNote for Windows Phone / Windows 10 Mobile.

If you made some unwanted changes, the only few ways to get back to the last good version I can think of are :

- Access previous versions history from [OneNote Online](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiKruCaoo7MAhXiCpoKHTvHB6UQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.onenote.com%2Fhrd&usg=AFQjCNGCKPKLFyeRqFSqI9vqsnMFTO6dkg&sig2=RFLLv-Ew7dvOxs0wN_dCCQ&bvm=bv.119408272,d.bGg), or also OneNote on your computer if available.
- If you have OneNote installed on a computer and it has the last good version of your notes, be sure to temporarily disable internet access (to avoid syncing the unwanted changes) and then open OneNote. Make a copy of the notes that you mistakenly changed, reconnect, sync and put it back.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's what I'm doing already. I was hoping for a undo function hidden somewhere that I was missing...